# Internet Explorer JavaScript - newline characters crashing script

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a onclick event in JavaScript that I have chosen to format as below:

```
        <a href="" onclick = "
        $('.white_content').html('<img src=\'/making.gif\'>');
        $.ajax({
          url: '/show_album.php?id=<?=$album['id']?>',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data){
            $('.white_content').html(data);
          },
          error: function(){
            alert('failed');
          }
        });
        return false;">
```

In FireFox, this is fine, but in Internet Explorer 8 the script is crashing because of the way I have layed out the code in new lines instead the onclick attribute.

Does anyone know a good way to fix this? I am still developing this page and others using similar code and I would like to keep a clean layout as opposed to all on one line.

If I inspect the onclick attribute in Internet Explorer developer tools I find each line seperated by several strange boxes that I assume represent unknown characters, obviously in IE, this is causing the error.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to have this much JS inline? You'd save yourself a lot of trouble if you would move it out, especially since you seem to be using jQuery already..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following instead:

```
<script>

function myOnclick() {

        $('.white_content').html('<img src=\'/making.gif\'>');
        $.ajax({
          url: '/show_album.php?id=<?=$album['id']?>',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data){
            $('.white_content').html(data);
          },
          error: function(){
            alert('failed');
          }
        });
        return false;
}
</script>
    <a href="" onclick="return myOnclick();">
```